# install X11 libraries and header files in user account centOS

Tags: x11, software-installation, non-root-user

I would like to install X11 libraries and header files in my own account (not root) for further use.

What other libs do I need to install for that? Where can I find the source codes and installation guide?

Truely, I want to install "ncview" software (http://meteora.ucsd.edu/~pierce/ncview_home_page.html) in my centOS linux. In the root, the system does not contain "X11" in the /usr/include. So, I want to install it in my own account.

Thanks for looking into it.

Comment: What media/file types are you installing from?  The answers here are probably relevant:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18787375/how-do-i-extract-the-contents-of-an-rpm

Answer (score 1):

As noted by @andrew-henle, the q/a *[How do I extract the contents of an rpm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18787375/how-do-i-extract-the-contents-of-an-rpm)* gives some information which could be useful.  If you want to compile [**`ncview`**](http://meteora.ucsd.edu/~pierce/ncview_home_page.html) and have no ability to *install* packages, you *could* find RPMs for the missing pieces, download them and copy the files to your home directory.

If you do that, suppose you put those under `$HOME/mystuff`.  Then under *that* directory, make subdirectories `bin`, `lib` (or `lib64`), `include` (and `include/X11`) and `share`.  Copy the files extracted from the RPMs to the corresponding location in the "mystuff" tree.

Set these environment variables to help the `ncview` configure-script:

`CFLAGS` to `-I$HOME/mystuff/include`
  `LDFLAGS` to `-L$HOME/mystuff/lib -L$HOME/mystuff/lib64`

Then run the configure-script for `ncview`.  It will probably find that you overlooked something.  Get that, put it in the `mystuff` tree.  Repeat until you get it to compile.

Likely those packages have shared libraries.  If so, you will need a workaround to get `ncview` to *run*, and probably just to configure it.  Set this environment variable to help:

`LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/mystuff/lib:$HOME/mystuff/lib64`

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will do as per your suggestions and will update the status.